# Getting post size at Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a proper way to find out what the size is of one post in Wordpress? Is there a plugin or something like that, or even a way to find it on phpmyadmin?

Edit: I can get the `average_row_length` in phpmyadmin of a table, but I want to do this for just ONE ROW (so no average, but the precise size).

Comment: What size are you referring to?

Comment: The size of one single post. For example: if I add a certain post, I would like to see what the size is of that post and so on. I can see on phpmyadmin that the total size of wp_posts is 58 MB, but I would like to see that per post.

Comment: Not a real answer. If your posts tabel gets too big consider deleting revisions. WP by default will keep infinite number of revisions, restrict it to ~10 http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions

Comment: Yeah, I am deleting revisions, that's not the problem. The problem is that I can't see how big/small one particular post is, that's what I want to see.

Comment: check this: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?131652-size-of-a-row-in-mysql  Apparently it can't be done with sql. `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts'` will give some info on the whole table

Comment: Yes, that gets the size of the table wp_posts, but not from ONE particular post. Besides, they are averages. I had seen the link, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Silly solution:

1. Open up phpmyadmin
2. Navigate to wp_posts
3. Click the checkmark next to the row you want to check.
4. Scroll down and click the Export icon at the bottom of the table.
5. Check the filesize of the exported row.

Alternately, you could order the table based on the length of a field, say `post_content`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_posts` 
ORDER BY LENGTH(  'post_content' ) DESC
```

That's just post content though...a lot of data gets saved into the wp_postmeta table as well, so I'm not sure how useful this line of thinking is.